# Criminal record check

Tags: canada, criminal-records

I had been convicted and got a letter from New Zealand immigration to leave the country. So after 9 months I'm applying for a student visa in Canada. Can someone tell me please if Canada immigration has any right to check my criminal and immigration record from New Zealand? No stamp on my passport.

Comment: I would expect that Canadian Immigration has every right to check your criminal and immigration background, whether New Zealand or any other country. Whether any criminal background would be a problem with Canadian Immigration would probably depend on the classification and severity of the criminal offense as well as how long ago it was.

Comment: what was ur offense? how did the application go?

Answer (score 1):

If you're intending to try to hide your conviction from the Canadian immigration authorities, that is a very ill-advised strategy. You will get caught. Maybe not straight away, but it will come back to haunt you. Best to tell them up front (when they ask), then it doesn't matter whether they have the "right" to ask New Zealand about convictions or not.

Answer (score 0):

Canada and New Zealand are both part of Five Eyes, so I would presume one can easily check the criminal/immigration records of the other.

Whether or not you have a stamp in your passport doesn't matter, everything is computerised these days.

Comment: Everything is indeed computerized these days however not all information is readily available. I was curious so looked up Five Eyes - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Eyes as well as this article https://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/dec/02/history-of-5-eyes-explainer I suppose any problems may stem from the severity and classification of the offense.